# git show log, status, commit or different repo but remote origin has correct url

Tags: git, github, pycharm

I have .git in multiple folders. when I open git bash in one of these folder, git will recognize the correct origin (url of the repo existed on github) and show correct log, commit, status of that repo.

but for some unknown reason, open git bash from any of the folder git will only show log, status of one repo (lets call it repo_1 ) eventhough "git remote -v" changes.

I suspect that there is something wrong with git init bare. Also, before I have this problem "repo_1" was acting weird. If I remember it correctly, I couldn't pull or push from repo_1 because, for some reason, repo_1 has no branch (timeline may not be accurate because I don't know what is going on)

so to fix "having no branch" problem, I unset git-bare in coifg, and I could push pull anything from repo_1. This is where the problem started.

Also, there is no .git in repo1, and there is hook, ref folders and COMMIT_EDITMSG, config, description, FETCH_HEAD, HEAD, index, ORIG_HEAD files that poped up.

Answer (score 0):

> there is no `.git` in repo1

That makes sense if it is a bare repository: no files, only a `.git` *content*.

> open git bash from any of the folder git will only show log, status of one repo (lets call it repo_1 )

If those `.git` are the result of `repo1` being cloned, that would be normal.
Or it could be the result of a `GIT_DIR` environment variable still referring to repo1 folder.